# How can I add PWM to my BLDC code using port manipulation?

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, port-mapping

I have the following code, which currently uses 6 output pins (pins 8 - 13) from the Arduino to my inverter circuit, which controls a BLDC motor. The code is fine and it works, however I want to add PWM using port manipulation and not `analogWrite`, as this is not fast enough for this application.

I know for example I could write `OCR1B = 200`, which sets the duty cycle of pin 10 to 200 and replaces the `analogWrite` function, but I do not know where to put this in my code. Also, do I need 3 PWM pins as the commutation of a BLDC motor is done in 6 steps in order to do 1 full revolution, or do I only need 1 PWM pin?

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(A0, INPUT); // sensor inputs
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  DDRB  |= B00111111; // Sets D8, D9, D10, D11, D12 and D13 as OUTPUT
  PORTB &= B11000000; // D8 to D13 LOW
}

void loop() {
  switch (PINC) {
    case 3:
      PORTB |= _BV(PB3); // set pin 11 high
      PORTB |= _BV(PB5); // set pin 13 high
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB0); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB1); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB4); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB2); //set low
      break;
    case 2:
      PORTB |= _BV(PB3); // set pin 11 high
      PORTB |= _BV(PB4); // set pin 12 high
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB5); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB2); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB1); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB0); //set low
      break;
    case 6:
      PORTB |= _BV(PB2); // set pin 10 high
      PORTB |= _BV(PB4); // set pin 12 high
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB0); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB1); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB3); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB5); //set low
      break;
    case 4:
      PORTB |= _BV(PB2); // set pin 10 high
      PORTB |= _BV(PB0); // set pin 8 high
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB1); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB5); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PD3); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PD4); //set low
      break;
    case 5:
      PORTB |= _BV(PB1); // set pin 9 high
      PORTB |= _BV(PB0); // set pin 8 high
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB2); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB4); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB5); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PD4); //set low
      break;
    case 1:
      PORTB |= _BV(PB1); // set pin 9 high
      PORTB |= _BV(PB5); // set pin 13 high
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB0); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB4); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB3); //set low
      PORTB &= ~_BV(PB2); //set low
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?